# avr/io.h don't include the appropriate avr/ioXXX.h file

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, eclipse

I'm facing a problem on Eclipse IDE that when compiling my project (which has `#include <avr/io.h>`), the compiler includes `avr/iom16.h` (for ATmega16) instead of `avr/iom32.h` (for my ATmega32). It appears when I press ctrl + click on any constant like `DDR` in my program, It opens the `avr/iom16.h` file which means it was included.

I've checked the compiler options of the project and found that the control switch option `-mmcu=atmega32` is fine, the same is for assembler options and linker options.

I've tried to make a new project, chosen target hardware as `Atmega 32` -as I usually do-, copied my source files into the new project, compiled the project, but the problem persists.

A strange thing also need to be mentioned is when I open the file `avr/io.h` after compiling, it is showing all the controller constants in gray background (which means they are not defined) except for this one `__AVR_ATmega32__` in white background (which means it is defined). The following is the two lines of code that appears with a white background:

```
#elif defined (__AVR_ATmega32__)
#  include <avr/iom32.h>
```

So, what is making the trouble then? is it could be something in the earlier preprocessing stages?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't place too much trust in the coloring of things in an IDE window.  This is typically *not* a result of evaluation by the actual compiler.  Look at what flags are being passed to gcc that could pre-define things, and look up the built in defines; in general I would *not expect* the -mmcu to define things to pass to the code.  Also consider just doing a full text search (`grep -r` or whatever IDE function) for some of these keywords in the codebase.

Comment: Without having the AVR plugin installed and not even Eclipse on my current machine, just my 2 cents. What Eclipse shows to you it not what the compiler sees. But you can setup Eclipse for this, I would search the preferences for something like "scanner" and see which command (most probably some GCC call) with which options are set. At this entry the MCU should be corrected if wrong. Did you search the web with "AVR ATmega32 Eclipse code analysis"?

Comment: Please remove the avrdude tag as it has no relevance to the issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've written this command on the terminal `avr-gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` it showed me all the predefined macros in avr-gcc. I used `grep` to find anything in relation to `m16` or `16` or `mmcu` but found nothing that may affect the target hardware.

Comment: You neglected to put your -mmcu in the test command line.  It looks like that should actually produce the `__AVR_ATmega32__` if  done right.  Otherwise you can define things with -D on the command line but the format of that one is the sort of thing set by the compiler, contrary to my earlier thought.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I put `-mmcu=atmega32` in the command and it produced the right outuput `#define __AVR_ATmega32__ 1`

Comment: It's evil but you might try putting `#error why does this get used?` at the top of the file you don't want included to ee if that gives you information on how it is getting included.  Remember to change it back!

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried this and there is no problem. It seems like there is a problem with the Eclipse GUI, but the compiler works fine. I't still opens the wrong .h file when I press `ctrl` + click on some constant, but I can assure that the compiler does open the right .h file. I generated intermediate files through `-save-temps` option in avr-gcc and it showed that the right .h file (`avr/iom32.h`) is expanded.

Comment: There's still some strange things happen in Eclipse. When I close a project it forgets all symbols from `avr/io.h` and put a `?` on them, but when I compile the project, it removes those warnings. I think it needs an update.

Comment: "There's still some strange things happen in Eclipse."  Sums it up - status by design. If you feel like it would be more productive to spend time debugging your application instead of debugging the IDE, Eclipse is not for you.

Comment: @Lundin You should be more patient with newbies like me. Anyway, I found that the problem was with the C/C++ Indexer in Eclipse. I unchecked a setting called "index source files not included in the build" and the Open Declaration feature worked fine! (works by ctrl+click a declaration or F3 when the cursor is on a declaration). It was leading me to the wrong .h file but now it works fine. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @GamalOthman I'm far more patient with newbies than with Eclipse. It's the only IDE that forces you constantly fiddle around with various linker options like these. Professional IDEs handle that for you and just work out of the box.